# Using a load balancer instead of Apache to throttle transactions from specific IP's

Tags: apache-httpd, load-balancing

I have two Apache instances behind a load balancer that I transfer the requests to, depending on the request type.

Now what I want: when I get too many transactions from an IP address, I want to block that IP for few seconds and send back some response to the client that you have sent too many requests.

So now the question: is there any way that we can handle this situation on my load balancer rather then calling my instances.

How can I handle this on Apache? I am using Apache version 2.2.

Comment: You might want to give details on your load balancer, if that's what you're interested in re-configuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to setup mod_evasive in Apache.

From [mod_evasive on Apache](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache-tips-and-tricks/modevasive-on-apache)

> mod_evasive is an evasive maneuvers module for Apache that provides
>   evasive action in the event of an HTTP DoS attack or brute force
>   attack. It is also designed to be a detection and network management
>   tool, and can be easily configured to talk to ipchains, firewalls,
>   routers, and more. mod_evasive presently reports abuse via email and
>   syslog facilities.

To install it in Debian:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-evasive
```

Edit then mods-available/evasive.conf. Your values may vary depending on how many vhosts you have on the server.

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
DOSHashTableSize 2048
DOSPageCount 50                    <---- visites to site in the given time
DOSSiteCount 500                   <---- to pages
DOSPageInterval 2.0                <---- 2 seconds
DOSSiteInterval 1.0
DOSBlockingPeriod 600.0             <--- seconds
DOSLogDir /var/log/apache2/evasive
DOSWhitelist 127.0.0.1
DOSWhitelist x.x.x.*
</IfModule>
```

For enabling the new `mod_evasive` configuration, you have to restart Apache.

You might also be interested in commercial services like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com) or Amazon [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).