# DDoS attacks to my Apache/Nodejs server?

Tags: apache-httpd, proxy

I checked by various netstat commands that many connections are made to my VPS Debian server.
I have NodeJS app running behind Apache2 proxy pass and when I want to open this app its really slow (5-10secs to load).
DDos protection from my hosting not working and I still see hundreds of connections from countries like China, Ukraine and Russia. Everytime I block those IP addresses using firewalld new appear...

How to block ALL countries from connecting to my server EXCEPT one or two countries I choose? Do I really must use some kind of list of ranges and block them all and update it properly? Or I can just do "BLOCK ALL EXCEPT "

BTW: Xtables-addons not working anymore (https://github.com/openwrt/packages/issues/7927)

Comment: https://daenney.github.io/2017/01/07/geoip-filtering-iptables

Comment: and where I am getting this geoIP data from?

Comment: Who is supposed to use this site? See related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282734/using-a-load-balancer-instead-of-apache-to-throttle-transactions-from-specific-i/282753#282753

Comment: @Rui F Riberio Its for public but only in my Country

Comment: Is it possible that people in holidays or nationals living abroad need to visit it?

Comment: Maybe, but I must somehow filter those 400 fake connections

Comment: @PhilipCouling https://github.com/openwrt/packages/issues/7927